# What is the equation describing the relationship beteen photocurrent and voltage in photoelectric effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

Keeping the intensity and frequency of light from the source fixed, the value of current in the circuit can be plotted against different voltage values, which look like this.
Most textbooks on photoelectric effect tells that the graph is experimentally obtained.
Can this be theoretically obtained?
What is the equation corresponding to this plot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the curve depends on the energy distribution curve of the emitted electrons (the photoemission spectrum), which is related to the density of states of the material, so there is no general theory.

One can make approximations, like a flat DoS, escape depth according to the "Universal Curve", a flat surface. Then it should be possible to obtain a function. Of course zero below the stopping potential, when only electrons emitted perpendicular to the surface can just make it to the anode.

With less retardation, the range of angles will become larger and also electrons with less kinetic energy than the maximal value of $E_k = hf-W_f$ can make it to the anode.

At accelerating voltages, all emitted electrons will arrive at the anode. This gives the saturation current.

Comment: @ Pieter Can  you give a reference to some paper or book which already contains such calculations?

Comment: @ManasDogra You could try google with search terms like "vacuum photodiode" "current voltage characteristic".

Comment: The significant measurement is the voltage which prevent all electrons from reaching the collector (for a given photon frequency).  In your equation $E_k$ = eV  and $W_f$ is the energy required for an electron to leave the emitting surface.